# How to import an excel file into a Webapp (javascript/d3/html)

Tags: javascript, html, excel, d3.js

I am still quite new to data visualization but learning quickly.
I am trying to create a small webapp in which the user can provide an excel spreadsheet and then the webapp would create a data visualization of this spreadsheet. 
I have the datavisualization part working with a dataset that is just preprogrammede as a variable (array). But I would like to ask help in creating the option for the user to "upload" their own excel file and then put the data from the spreadsheet into an array variable and run the d3 datavisualization on that.

Comment: What kind of backend technology are you looking at? Javascript only there'S [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways

1. Export from excel to csv
2. you can use a libary for PHP

http://faisalman.github.io/simple-excel-php/api/0.3/
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel
...

if you have more Questions about that you can write me and i help you

Comment: Hands down the easiest way is going to be to save the excel file as a CSV. Some of the PHP libs i've used in the past can be SUPER slow depending on the file size.